# почему статические поля не сериализуются?(java)

Tags: java

почему статические поля не сериализуются?(java)

Comment: а почему должны?

Answer (score 1):

Сериализация используется для записи состояния экземпляра, а не класса.
Статические поля связаны с классом, а не экземпляром, по этому после десериализации они будут повторно инициализированы при загрузке класса.
Если у вас есть изменяемые `static` поля, то изменения будут потеряны.

Answer (score 0):

Статические члены связаны с классом, а не с экземплярами, поэтому нет смысла включать их при сериализации экземпляра.